# Python pandas ranking dataframe columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to use rank function on two columns in my dataframe.

**Problem**:

One of the column contains blank values which is not allowing me to do groupby before ranking.

***ERROR*:** ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1122 elements, new values have 1814 elements

```
 df_source['col1'] = df_source['col1'].apply(lambda \
    x:x.strip()).replace('',np.nan)

 df_source['Rank'] = df_source.groupby(by=['col0','col1']) \
    ['col1'].transform(lambda x: x.rank(na_option='bottom'))


      **Actual:**

        col0   col1
        98630  a
               a
        90211  a
        31111  a
               b
        23323  c

    **Expected**

        col0   col1  Rank
        98630  a      1
               a      2
        90211  a      1
        31111  a      1
               b      1
        23323  c      1
```

Comment: What if you do `df['col0'] = df['col0'].replace('', np.nan).ffill()` first before doing this?

Comment: I am getting same error

Answer (score 1):

This code gives the expected result. I have tried to avoid groupby function for columns with null values.

```
    df['col0'] = df['col0'].replace('', np.nan)
    df_int = df.loc[df['col0'].notnull(), 'col1'].unique()
    df = df[~(df['col0'].isin(df_int) & df['col1'].isnull())]
```